# Doctrine method find() returns a proxy object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm running two equal find methods. One is returning a proxy, the other one is returning a real Entity object.

I can't find a reason why doctrine would handle both differently.
Do you have any idea why my first Entity is returned as a proxy?

This project is running:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
"symfony/symfony": "5.4.*",
```

Following my Test Controller Action:

```
public function startAction(InstitutionRepository $institutionRepository, CountryRepository $countryRepository): Response
{

    $result = $institutionRepository->find(266);
    $result2 = $countryRepository->find(1);
    return $this->json([$result, $result2]);
}
```

None of the Entity classes have black magic inside and look equal:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Institutions.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="institutions")
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InstitutionRepository")
 */
class Institution
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="institution", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getCode(): string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
    public function setCode(string $code): void
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Country Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Countries.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="countries", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="code", columns={"code"})})
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code.
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And both Repository methods are almost empty:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Country;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Country>
 */
class CountryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Country::class);
    }
}
```

InstitutionRepository:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

use Database\OrganisationBundle\Entity\Institution;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Country>
 */
class InstitutionRepository  extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Institution::class);
    }


}
```

The serialized Result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 266,
    "code": "LGSE_QS_IN",
    "name": "LGSE QS Test Institution",
    "__initializer__": null,
    "__cloner__": null,
    "__isInitialized__": true
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "AF",
    "name": "Afghanistan"
  }
]
```

I'm totally out of ideas.
Maybe someone experienced something like this already with Symfony and Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your InstitutionRepository.

```
@extends ServiceEntityRepository<Country>
```

should be

```
@extends ServiceEntityRepository<Institution>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thank you for the hint. I can't reproduce it now as I reverted my changes. I think this is not relevant for the logic of how the code works. The doc block is only relevant for documentation and autocompletion within the IDE.